# Cannot instantiate the type Animator class

Tags: android, animation

```
public abstract class SupportAnimator extends Animator {

WeakReference<RevealAnimator> mTarget;

public SupportAnimator(RevealAnimator target) {
    mTarget = new WeakReference<>(target);
}

/**
 * @return true if using native android animation framework, otherwise is
 *         nineoldandroids
 */
public abstract boolean isNativeAnimator();

/**
 * @return depends from {@link android.os.Build.VERSION} if sdk version
 *         {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#LOLLIPOP} and greater will
 *         return {@link android.animation.Animator}
 */
public abstract Object get();

/**
 * Starts this animation. If the animation has a nonzero startDelay, the
 * animation will start running after that delay elapses. A non-delayed
 * animation will have its initial value(s) set immediately, followed by
 * calls to
 * {@link android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener#onAnimationStart(android.animation.Animator)}
 * for any listeners of this animator.
 *
 * <p>
 * The animation started by calling this method will be run on the thread
 * that called this method. This thread should have a Looper on it (a
 * runtime exception will be thrown if this is not the case). Also, if the
 * animation will animate properties of objects in the view hierarchy, then
 * the calling thread should be the UI thread for that view hierarchy.
 * </p>
 *
 */
public abstract void start();

/**
 * Adds a listener to the set of listeners that are sent events through the
 * life of an animation, such as start, repeat, and end.
 *
 * @param listener
 *            the listener to be added to the current set of listeners for
 *            this animation.
 */
public abstract void addListener(AnimatorListener listener);

/**
 * Returns whether this Animator is currently running (having been started
 * and gone past any initial startDelay period and not yet ended).
 *
 * @return Whether the Animator is running.
 */
public abstract boolean isRunning();

/**
 * Cancels the animation. Unlike {@link #end()}, <code>cancel()</code>
 * causes the animation to stop in its tracks, sending an
 * {@link AnimatorListener#onAnimationCancel()} to its listeners, followed
 * by an {@link AnimatorListener#onAnimationEnd()} message.
 *
 * <p>
 * This method must be called on the thread that is running the animation.
 * </p>
 */
public abstract void cancel();

/**
 * Ends the animation. This causes the animation to assign the end value of
 * the property being animated, then calling the
 * {@link AnimatorListener#onAnimationEnd()} method on its listeners.
 *
 * <p>
 * This method must be called on the thread that is running the animation.
 * </p>
 */
public void end() {
}

/**
 * This method tells the object to use appropriate information to extract
 * starting values for the animation. For example, a AnimatorSet object will
 * pass this call to its child objects to tell them to set up the values. A
 * ObjectAnimator object will use the information it has about its target
 * object and PropertyValuesHolder objects to get the start values for its
 * properties. A ValueAnimator object will ignore the request since it does
 * not have enough information (such as a target object) to gather these
 * values.
 */
public void setupStartValues() {
}

/**
 * This method tells the object to use appropriate information to extract
 * ending values for the animation. For example, a AnimatorSet object will
 * pass this call to its child objects to tell them to set up the values. A
 * ObjectAnimator object will use the information it has about its target
 * object and PropertyValuesHolder objects to get the start values for its
 * properties. A ValueAnimator object will ignore the request since it does
 * not have enough information (such as a target object) to gather these
 * values.
 */
public void setupEndValues() {
}

/**
 * Experimental feature
 */
public SupportAnimator reverse() {
    if (isRunning()) {
        return null;
    }

    RevealAnimator target = mTarget.get();
    if (target != null) {
        return target.startReverseAnimation();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * <p>
 * An animation listener receives notifications from an animation.
 * Notifications indicate animation related events, such as the end or the
 * repetition of the animation.
 * </p>
 */
public interface AnimatorListener {
    /**
     * <p>
     * Notifies the start of the animation.
     * </p>
     */
    void onAnimationStart();

    /**
     * <p>
     * Notifies the end of the animation. This callback is not invoked for
     * animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.
     * </p>
     */
    void onAnimationEnd();

    /**
     * <p>
     * Notifies the cancellation of the animation. This callback is not
     * invoked for animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.
     * </p>
     */
    void onAnimationCancel();

    /**
     * <p>
     * Notifies the repetition of the animation.
     * </p>
     */
    void onAnimationRepeat();
}

/**
 * <p>
 * Provides default implementation for AnimatorListener.
 * </p>
 */
public static abstract class SimpleAnimatorListener implements
        AnimatorListener {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat() {

    }
}

 }
```

Its an abstract Class and extends by `Animator`.

and when I use this in next class

```
  if (LOLLIPOP_PLUS) {

        return new SupportAnimator(
                android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view,
                        centerX, centerY, startRadius, endRadius),
                revealLayout);

    }

    ObjectAnimator reveal = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(revealLayout,
            CLIP_RADIUS, startRadius, endRadius);
    reveal.addListener(new RevealAnimator.RevealFinishedIceCreamSandwich(
            revealLayout, layerType));
    return new SupportAnimator(reveal, revealLayout);

}
```

the return new SupportAnimator returns an exception of Cannot instantiate the type SupportAnimator,

its use for Circular Reveal animation and i use this in eclipse, is this suitable to work fine.

Comment: you forgot to ask the question...

Comment: exception of Cannot instantiate the type SupportAnimator?  how to solve it